# How can I prevent external comments from being stored in T-SQL object definitions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, comments

In T-SQL, I occasionally have to alter table and view definitions in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. When I do, there's often many required changes so I automate the creation a T-SQL script to help. In this script, I insert comments that are relevant to the creation of the script. There are also comments within the object definitions themselves, which are relevant to the object they are in.

I have found that comments both inside and outside the object definitions are stored in the object definition, and this is not desired. Consider the following T-SQL snippet:

```
/* This is comment 1 */

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[view_name]
AS
SELECT
    field_name1,
    field_name2, /* This is comment 2 */
    field_name3
...
```

I have found that both comment 1 and comment 2 are stored within `view_name`'s object definition. Comment 2 is fine--I want it there. But I don't want comment 1 to be stored with the object's definition. How I can prevent comment 1 from being stored?

Comment: Simple. Don't add comments where you don't want them or remove accordingly.

Comment: @ChrisBint, The comments are useful in the context of the T-SQL script, which I store as a database version upgrade script. I want them there in the script. But I don't want them to be stored in the object definition when I run the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `go` after the external comment

```
/* This is comment 1 */
go

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[view_name]
...
```

Comment: This does work! However I'm hoping there's an answer that doesn't require GO after each comment. Some object definitions require multiple external comments ("comment 1"-types in the example), and I'd then have to track if one or more comments have been added, and if so, then add the GO just before the object definition. If there are no more answers today, I'll mark this as the correct answer. Thank you!